# How to create a new container from container?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

Is there a way to create a new StructureMap container from an existing one? I want to have all the dependencies from the fisrt container plus another ones in the new container.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I have a container with some dependencies specified inside a project. I have another project which references the first project, and I want to create a container in this project to use the dependencies established on the first project, plus other dependencies added only for this one.

Comment: A single application (single app domain) should usually have only a single container instance, independently of the number of project / assemblies that application has. Use that single container to register all dependencies from all projects.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment, and deleted my last one XD. I tried to have a single container, but the dependencies between the projects didn't let me. However, you gave me an idea. I will add the dependencies to the container from the project who needs them, and not from the container's project, to avoid circular dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [nested container](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2010/02/10/nested-containers-in-structuremap-2-6-1/) pulls all non-transient instances (Singleton, HttpContext, ThreadLocalStorage scoped etc) from its parent container. Once disposed, it will dispose all transient objects that implements `IDisposable` in it.

You create a nested container using:

```
using (IContainer nested = ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer())
{
    var service = nested.GetInstance<IService>();
    service.DoSomething();
}
```

Nested containers are generally used when you need fine grained control over the lifetime of the transients in them, such as creating and disposing of objects used in a per `HttpRequest` scenario.